# HTTPS not working for domain, but works for subdomain

Tags: https, apache2

I've got a subdomain set up for my nextcloud instance at nc.example.com, and I have set up a new virtual host for my main website that I will look at creating at example.com. I ran certbot on example.com, and initially it worked, then I accidentally ran certbot again, but ctrl C'd out of it, but now HTTPS on example.com does not seem to work, even though when I run certbox certificates, it's listed there.

Initially example.com would work, but now it will only work when I include www., but it's running on a HTTP connection.

My nc.example.com works fine with HTTPS and no www., in my DNS records I've added an A record pointing to 174.129.25.170 to fix the naked domain issue with having to include www., but as I mentioned, it was working briefly and now it's not.

[A Record Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIOWi.png)

I feel like I've just messed something simple up cause it was working initially. Any assistance would be appreciated because I'm still learning this stuff. I'm running apache2 on an Ubuntu 22.04 AWS EC2 instance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I fixed this literally 3 minutes after posting this.

I ran `sudo certbot`

and it asked which names I'd like to activate HTTPS for, it listed three domains

1. example.com
2. nc.example.com
3. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I selected 3, and it seems to have fixed my problem, but now I have 3 certificates, will this matter?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).